# Aliasing a database field from model class in nestjs/sequelize

Tags: typescript, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I am beginning with NestJs and chose to use Sequelize for database operations, I would like to know if it is possible to alias a database column in the model class as follows:

```js
@ForeignKey(() => Relation)
@Column
relationId: number // This field's name in the database is relation_id
```

Basically, I want a way if that is possible to tell Sequelize that the database column name corresponding to `relationId` is `relation_id`

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the options object to the `@Column` decorator

```js
@ForeignKey(() => Relation)
@Column({ field: 'relation_id' })
relationId: number
```